# Videogular volume control is not visible in apple IPad

Tags: angularjs, videogular

Implemented videogular html player.All works well in desktop but in case of Apple IPAD the volumne control is not visible.And one major issue is on clicking full-screen of videogular player,video does not plays in videogular instead it opens up in the apple's native player(i.e., quick player).
How can I prevent video from playing in native player in IPAD and display volumne control for vidoegular.?

Is there any fixes available.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volume button is not shown on mobile devices because you can't change with the native API the volume, user must use hardware buttons to change the volume.

Additionally, on mobile devices you can't set HTML elements to fullscreen, only the video element. If you need Videogular controls in fullscreen mode you can try to use "vg-native-fullscreen":

```
<videogular vg-native-fullscreen="false">
    <!-- content -->
</videogular>
```

However, this is an emulated fullscreen and user will see the browser navigation bar.